# How to get value of object inside object using System.Text.Json in .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, json.net, system.text.json, .net-core-3.1

Created a **.Net Core 3.1** Web Application and posted request where Requested model looks like,

```
public class RequestPayload
    {
        public string MessageName { get; set; }

        public object Payload { get; set; }
    }
```

I am very new to core 3.1 and struggling to get the value of Payload property, Can anyone help me on this?

While finding the solution I also compared **Newtonsoft** and **System.Text.Json** and got **Error**.

Using **Newtonsoft** I am **able** to Serialize and Deserialize a model shown below,

```
public class RequestPayload
    {
        public string MessageName { get; set; }

        public object Payload { get; set; }

        //Problem is here -> TYPE
        public Type PayloadType { get; set; }
    }
```

but using **System.Text.Json** I am **not** 
While **serializing** got error "System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported."

To test **deserialization**, somehow created JSON and tries to deserialize it using System.Text.Json but getting an error "System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'The JSON value could not be converted to System.Type. "

Used **System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer**, is it an issue or is there any other possibility to make this works?

Comment: Please, provide the JSON payload.

Comment: {"MessageName":"any","Payload":{"Name":"hi"}} or you are asking for serialization and desialization issue? If so ,to create that json I use newtonsoft serialization and created json , so it is proper.

Comment: So what I mean by that is to create that json I have create instance of RequestPayload class and set property whose type is TYPE then using newtonsoft serialization created json.

Comment: Why do you need to have the `Type` property in your class? Can you get away with not having it?

Comment: Requirements is I have one application where I will create RequestPayload and set Type property (which is not fixed this can be any class). After creating RequestPayload using rest call I will send it to second application where I only need payload type not whole instance of payload inside RequestPayload. And at second application I will use the type of payload model to parsing the contents using razor compiler. Yes there has to be different approach to achieve it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I am very new to core 3.1 and struggling to get the value of Payload property, Can anyone help me on this?

For `System.Object` properties, **unlike** `Newtonsoft.Json`, `System.Text.Json` does **not** try to infer the `type` of the JSON payload for primitive values (such as `true`, `12345.67`, `"hello"`). Similarly, for complex JSON values like objects and arrays (such as `{"Name":"hi"}` or `[1, 2, 3]`), the object property is set as a boxed `JsonElement` that represents the passed-in JSON. This is similar to how `Newtonsoft.Json` stores a `JObject` into the `object property` for complex types.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement?view=netcore-3.1

Like how you would with Newtonsoft.Json's `JObject`, you can traverse and access values within the JSON Document Object Model (DOM) using the `JsonElement` and call conversion APIs on it to get .NET values (such as `GetProperty(String)` and `GetInt32()`).

The following example shows how you can access the `Payload` values, once you have deserialized the JSON into a `RequestPayload`.

```
private static void ObjectPropertyExample()
{
    using JsonDocument doc = JsonDocument.Parse("{\"Name\":\"Darshana\"}");
    JsonElement payload = doc.RootElement.Clone();

    var requestPayload = new RequestPayload
    {
        MessageName = "message",
        Payload = payload
    };

    string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(requestPayload);
    Console.WriteLine(json);
    // {"MessageName":"message","Payload":{"Name":"Darshana"}}

    RequestPayload roundtrip = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<RequestPayload>(json);

    JsonElement element = (JsonElement)roundtrip.Payload;
    string name = element.GetProperty("Name").GetString();
    Assert.Equal("Darshana", name);
}
```

> While finding the solution I also compared Newtonsoft and System.Text.Json and got Error.

Even though serializing a class that contains a `System.Type` property is OK to do, it is **not** recommended, especially for web applications (there are potential issues with information disclosure though).

On the other hand, **deserialization** JSON into a class that contains a `Type` property, especially using `Type.GetType(untrusted-string-input)` is **definitely not recommended** since it introduces potential security vulnerabilities in your application.

This is why the built-in `System.Text.Json` intentionally **does not support** serializing/deserializing `Type` properties. The exception message you are seeing while serializing is because `Type` contains a cycle within its object graph and the `JsonSerializer` doesn't currently handle cycles. If you only care about serializing (i.e. writing) the class into JSON, you could create your own `JsonConverter<Type>` to add support for it (to produce the same JSON that `Newtonsoft.Json` would). Something like the following will work:

```
private class CustomJsonConverterForType : JsonConverter<Type>
{
    public override Type Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        // Caution: Deserialization of type instances like this 
        // is not recommended and should be avoided
        // since it can lead to potential security issues.

        // If you really want this supported (for instance if the JSON input is trusted):
        // string assemblyQualifiedName = reader.GetString();
        // return Type.GetType(assemblyQualifiedName);
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Type value,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        // Use this with caution, since you are disclosing type information.
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.AssemblyQualifiedName);
    }
}
```

You can then add the custom converter into the options and pass that to `JsonSerializer.Serialize`:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.Converters.Add(new CustomJsonConverterForType());
```

Consider **re-evaluating** why you need the `Type` property on your class that is being serialized and deserialized to begin with.

See https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/42712 for more information and context around why you shouldn't deserialize classes containing `Type` properties using `Type.GetType(string)`.

Here is more information on how to write a custom converter:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to

An approach that can work more safely (and hence what **I would recommend**) is to use a type discriminator enum which contains the list of statically known types that you expect and support and explicitly create those types based on the enum values within the `JsonConverter<Type>`.

Here's an example of what that would look like:

```
// Let's assume these are the list of types we expect for the `Type` property
public class ExpectedType1 { }
public class ExpectedType2 { }
public class ExpectedType3 { }

public class CustomJsonConverterForType : JsonConverter<Type>
{
    public override Type Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        TypeDiscriminator typeDiscriminator = (TypeDiscriminator)reader.GetInt32();

        Type type = typeDiscriminator switch
        {
            TypeDiscriminator.ExpectedType1 => typeof(ExpectedType1),
            TypeDiscriminator.ExpectedType2 => typeof(ExpectedType2),
            TypeDiscriminator.ExpectedType3 => typeof(ExpectedType3),
            _ => throw new NotSupportedException(),
        };
        return type;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Type value,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (value == typeof(ExpectedType1))
        {
            writer.WriteNumberValue((int)TypeDiscriminator.ExpectedType1);
        }
        else if (value == typeof(ExpectedType2))
        {
            writer.WriteNumberValue((int)TypeDiscriminator.ExpectedType2);
        }
        else if (value == typeof(ExpectedType3))
        {
            writer.WriteNumberValue((int)TypeDiscriminator.ExpectedType3);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }

    // Used to map supported types to an integer and vice versa.
    private enum TypeDiscriminator
    {
        ExpectedType1 = 1,
        ExpectedType2 = 2,
        ExpectedType3 = 3,
    }
}

private static void TypeConverterExample()
{
    var requestPayload = new RequestPayload
    {
        MessageName = "message",
        Payload = "payload",
        PayloadType = typeof(ExpectedType1)
    };

    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
    {
        Converters = { new CustomJsonConverterForType() }
    };

    string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(requestPayload, options);
    Console.WriteLine(json);
    // {"MessageName":"message","Payload":"payload","PayloadType":1}

    RequestPayload roundtrip = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<RequestPayload>(json, options);
    Assert.Equal(typeof(ExpectedType1), roundtrip.PayloadType);
}
```

Comment: Looking for way to get property(type is object) of request body of post method. Solution you have given has serialized and deserialized in the code but at post method, model is already deserialized and I don't need property of payload model but I need payload object itself, also didn't find method to get object like ``` jsonElement.GetValue() ``` of that object.